# How to rewrite state with rest syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to increase property in the state, but I have no idea how I can do it
help please, I have tried two days but got many troubles

```
export const initialState = {
  ids: [],
  basket: []
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      if (state.ids.indexOf(action.item.id) === -1) {
       // if new item add to basket
        return {
          ids: [...state.ids, action.item.id],
          basket: [...state.basket, action.item]
        }
      }
      else {
        if (state.basket.length > 0) {
          // state.basket[state.basket.length - 1].quantity += 1
        }
        return {
          ...state,
          // IT'S WRONG
          basket: [...state.basket, [state.basket.length - 1].quantity += 1]
        }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mutate state (`basket.quantity += 1`) when it should treated as immutable.

I believe you need to rethink how you structure your state if it gets so hard to immutably update a state.

```
export const initialState = {
  ids: [],
  basket: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
      if (state.ids.indexOf(action.item.id) === -1) {
        ...
      } else {
        ...

        const basketsShallowCopy = [...state.basket];
        const basketToUpdate = basketsShallowCopy.pop();
        const updatedBasked = {
          ...baskedToUpdate,
          quantity: basketToUpdate.quantity + 1,
        };

        basketsShallowCopy.push(updatedBasked);
        return {
          ...state,
          basket: basketsShallowCopy,
        };
      }
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: `const updatedBasked = {
            ...basketToUpdate,
            quantity: basketToUpdate.quantity + 1,
          };`